# Нужен поиск по собственным вопросам

Tags: предложение

Вот, допустим, я полгода назад где-то в комментариях своего вопроса обсуждал что-то. Помню, о чем шла речь, и помню, что там была важная информация, которую я по той или иной причине не успел усвоить, не понял, оставил на потом и забыл. И вот сейчас она мне понадобилась. Неудобно кликать по всем вопросам, перещелкивать страницы с вопросами и искать, кто же мне об этом говорил.

Можно создать инструмент "Поиск в собственных вопросах" (в том числе и в комментариях к ним и в ответах к ним), другой инструмент "Поиск в своих ответах и комментариях к чужим вопросам". Второй инструмент тоже может понадобиться, если вдруг через месяц узнал, что то новое и быстро нужно найти тот самый не совсем точный свой ответ и изменить его.

Comment: `is:q user:mine текст`

Comment: Английский текст в своих комментариях можно с помощью data.SE запроса найти. К примеру, вот [ваши комментарии со словом Java](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/264731/find-comments-by-user-and-text?UserId=208242&Text=Java)

Comment: @NickVolynkin никогда не использовал mine, только me